# How to see if element exists in a json file In Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I would like to check if a command exists in a JSON file.
Here is the JSON file:

```
{
    "commands":[
        {
            "name":"Help",
            "commandName":"help",
            "usage": "help",
            "function":"print"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
import json
def login():
    print("Oof")
while True:
    Command = input(">")
    with open("data.json") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data['commands']:
            if Command in data['commands']:
                if Command.lower() == p['commandName']:
                    eval(p["function"] + '()')
            else:
                print("Command '{}' does not exist, try 'help'.".format(Command))
```

But it doesn't seem to work... Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
cmd = input().lower()
if cmd in set(c["commandName"] for c in data["commands"]):
    # do something
else:
    print(f"Command {cmd} does not exist")
```